# Python : string with timezone to datetime object conversion

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I have a string like this

`dateStr = "Wed Mar 15 12:50:52 GMT+05:30 2017"`

which is IST time.

Is there any way to read the dateStr as per the specified timezone within the dateStr

i.e. GMT+05:30.
So that I can make datetime object directly.

I have tried to parse it using format

`format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z%z %Y"`

But it gives me error of format does not match.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
>>> dateStr = "Wed Mar 15 12:50:52 GMT+05:30 2017"
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse(dateStr)
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 15, 12, 50, 52, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -19800))
```

Comment: I have already tried this method.
When we apply this method on series of dates then it gives us warning.
like : Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware datetime.

You can see tzinfo is None. there should be something GMT or IST.